# ActionScript + Ruby

Tags: ruby, actionscript-3

I'm using WebSocket on ruby server.

```
require          'em-websocket'

def start_server(host, port)
  EM.run {
    EM::WebSocket.run(:host => host, :port => port) do |ws|
      ws.onopen {

      }
      ws.onmessage {
      }
      ws.onclose {

      }
    end
    puts 'Server is running at' + Time.now().to_s
  }
end

start_server('localhost', 8090)
```

I need to send request from ActionScript client. How I can do it?
My code doesn't work.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var request = new URLRequest("http://localhost:8090");
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        variables.exampleSessionId = new Date().getTime();
        variables.exampleUserLabel = "guest";
        request.data = variables;
        try {
            loader.load(request);

        } catch (error:Error) {
            trace("Unable to load requested document.");
        }
```

Maybe, you can suggest other implementation of ruby http server. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the Ruby side, but in AS3 the `URLLoader` is not meant to connect to a Web Socket, it's meant to load http resources. For Web Sockets in AS3 you must use a [`Socket`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html). There is no built in implementation of the [Web Socket standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) in AS3, but there are 3rd party libraries such as [AS3WebSocket](https://github.com/theturtle32/AS3WebSocket).